# vagrant and virtual box and the license file

Tags: vmware-fusion, vagrant

I got the following problem: I own a copy of vmware fusion 5 (license key with format XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX) and want to use the vagrant fusion plugin.

So, trying to get things to work following this [installation guide](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vmware/installation.html) I stumbled upon the license file. How do I get the vagrant-vmware-fusion plugin to work with my key instead of the license file?

Answer (score 2):

You need a separate license for running the Vagrant plugin for VMware Fusion.

More info [here](http://www.vagrantup.com/vmware#buy-now).

Comment: Are you sure, it says buy a `VMware Fusion 5 or 6 (Mac OS X)` license -- which I already own. I hate buying things twice ;)

Comment: Under the buy button there's a clarification note.

Comment: I agree - not very clear.